# How to configure Why Did You Render with NextJS 12

Tags: reactjs, next.js, babeljs, rerender, swc-compiler

Next.JS uses babel to configure the Why Did You Render.

```
module.exports = function (api) {
    const isServer = api.caller((caller) => caller?.isServer)
    const isCallerDevelopment = api.caller((caller) => caller?.isDev)

    const presets = [
        [
            'next/babel',
            {
                'preset-react': {
                    importSource:
                        !isServer && isCallerDevelopment
                            ? '@welldone-software/why-did-you-render'
                            : 'react'
                }
            }
        ]
    ]

    return {presets}
}
```

How can this be updated to Next.JS 12 without disabling SWC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After experimenting a bit, I came to the final conclusion:

You can do it via `next.config.js` configuration, which doesn't disable SWC, but there are a few things you should take care of:

- First you need to stop the devserver entirely;
- Then you have to wipe `.next` folder or whatever path is your build;
- Finally, create a folder called scripts, and create a file named `whyDidYouRender.js` inside it.

Now edit your config file

```js
// next.config.js:
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  /**
   * @param {{[key: string]: unknown}} config
   * @param {{isDev: boolean; isServer: boolean;}} options
   */
  webpack(config, { dev, isServer }) {
    // why did you render
    if (dev && !isServer) {
      const originalEntry = config.entry;
      config.entry = async () => {
        const wdrPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './scripts/whyDidYouRender.js')
        const entries = await originalEntry();
        if (entries['main.js'] && !entries['main.js'].includes(wdrPath)) {
          entries['main.js'].unshift(wdrPath);
        }
        return entries;
      };
    }

    return config;
  },
};
```

And edit whyDidYouRender file

```js
// scripts/whyDidYouRender.js
import React from 'react';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
    const whyDidYouRender = require('@welldone-software/why-did-you-render');
  // @ts-ignore
  whyDidYouRender(React, {
    trackAllPureComponents: true,
  });
}
```

If you still have trouble, you can replace this line:

`if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')`

with

`if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && typeof window === 'object')`

Or you can remove this check entirely, since this file is only supposed to be imported if webpack's option `dev` is true and option `isServer` is false

PS.: Please note that why-did-you-render may run silently if there are no issues, so no console messages doesn't necessarily means it's not running. You can create an issue to test it